# How to count values without the duplicate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Language used : js with react

I need to count how much "theme" I have but not if he's already count/exist

data example :

```
   movies = [{"id" : 1, "name": "Ps: i love you", "theme": { "id": 1, "name": "love"} }, 
    {"id" : 2, "name": "Holiday", "theme": { "id": 1, "name": "love"} }, 
    {"id" :3, "name": "Scary Movie", "theme": { "id": 2, "name": "horror"} }]
```

Here, i have two theme : love and horror.

I know how to get the number of theme but i don't want to count the duplicate, so here i only want to get "2" and no "3" .

what i am actually trying :

```
const movieTheme= movies.filter((item) => item.theme.name);
    const movieThemeCount = movieTheme.length;
    console.log(movieThemeCount ); // of course i'm here getting 3 instead of 2
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Ok i am trying :)

Comment: `new Set(movies.map(item => item.theme.name)).size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to create a unique list of themes. Use `map` and `filter` to shape your array however you require it. You should look into the Array.filter method itself, the third parameter `self` would have helped you a lot here :)

```js
const movies = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Ps: i love you', theme: { id: 1, name: 'love' } },
  { id: 2, name: 'Holiday', theme: { id: 1, name: 'love' } },
  { id: 3, name: 'Scary Movie', theme: { id: 2, name: 'horror' } }
];

const themes = movies
  .map((movie) => movie.theme)
  .filter((theme, index, self) => self.findIndex((t) => t.id === theme.id) === index);

console.log(themes); // [{"id":1,"name":"love"},{"id":2,"name":"horror"}]

console.log(themes.length); // 2
```

Comment: Life saver, just discover the self parameter! thank you, it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, try this, it is tested

```
movies = [{"id": 1, "name": "Ps: i love you", "theme": {"id": 1, "name": "love"}},
{"id": 2, "name": "Holiday", "theme": {"id": 1, "name": "love"}},
{"id": 3, "name": "Scary Movie", "theme": {"id": 2, "name": "horror"}}]


const movieTheme = []

movies.forEach((item) => {
   let exists = false
   for (let i = 0; i < movieTheme.length; i++) {
    if (movieTheme[i] === item.theme.name) {
        exists = true;
    }
}
if (exists) {
    return false
} else {
    movieTheme.push(item.theme.name)
    return item.theme.name;

}
});
const movieThemeCount = movieTheme.length;

console.log(movieTheme); 
console.log(movieThemeCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I writed what you need inside `handleCountTheme` function. It just use one loop inside to count `the number of theme`.

```js
 const movies = [{"id" : 1, "name": "Ps: i love you", "theme": { "id": 1, "name": "love"} }, 
    {"id" : 2, "name": "Holiday", "theme": { "id": 1, "name": "love"} }, 
    {"id" :3, "name": "Scary Movie", "theme": { "id": 2, "name": "horror"} }]

const handleCountTheme = (movies) => {
    const idList = []
    movies.forEach((item) => { 
        if(idList.includes(item.theme.id)) return;
        idList.push(item.theme.id);
    }) 
    return idList.length;
}

console.log(handleCountTheme(movies))
```